# Why are laptop hard disk drives so slow?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 2.5 inch 1TB 7200rpm hard drive in my laptop, I thought this would give a significant speed boost over the 5400rpm drive in my previous laptop.

And I have heard that desktop HDDs are faster than their 2.5 inch equivalents, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: I tried finding read write specs for 2.5 inch drives and I was unable to find anything reliable - so if you have some specs they would be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the specifications of each drive (beside the number and size of platters), and they are different on 2.5 and 3.5 inch plates. Smaller HDD are designed to use less power which leads to certain limitations. Some points to mention are:

interface speed  (bus and mainboard) usually slower

buffer size is smaller and is noticeable

seektime is slower

Answer (score 0):

"I have heard" are very very dangerous words. They mean totally nothing.

Many server HDDs are 'small' 2.5 inch drives that often smoke their consumer desktop counterparts. TSo its not size (and the only 10K rpm desktop drive on the market is 2.5 inches anyway)

Heat generation and power usage are two issues a laptop hdd needs to deal with - lower power use and heat generation would be what a laptop optimises for.

In *theory* desktop HDDs could have bigger buffers, more platters (so information could be seeked in more than one platter at once). Bigger buffers means that the HDDs can store data in ram (making better use of available bandwidth). They also have bigger platters (which could mean you need to seek over a larger area to find ram.). *Critically* a good desktop HDD is designed to be somewhat less conservative about head parking and going to sleep than a laptop.

And there's so much more to apparent speed - amount of ram (and how much pagefile you use!) for example.

If you want a *big* performance boost, pretty hard to go wrong with an SSD.